# Spring Session 1.2.2 and cookie.path

Tags: spring-boot, spring-session

when I use spring.session.store-type=jdbc server.session.cookie.path has no effect. But when I implement an own CookieSerializer it works. 
When I use spring.session.store-type=none server.session.cookie.path is effective.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you use Spring Boot judging by your reference of `server.session.cookie.path` configuration property - this property is used to configure path of the session cookie when session management is handled by your servlet container (Tomcat by default with Spring Boot).

If you use Spring Session, you're making your session management platform agnostic, meaning your servlet container is not in charge of handling those concerns any more.

This explains the behavior you're seeing - when Spring Session is not used for session management (`spring.session.store-type=none`) the servlet container session configuration properties (such as `server.session.cookie.path`) are effective, and when you do use Spring Session (`spring.session.store-type=jdbc`) they are not.